# Right answer picked up wrongly as an audit, because somebody marked it as a new question?

Tags: support, bug, review-audits

[This answer](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/444928) appeared in the First Post queue:

> Change it the way you would your videos library by right-clicking the folder on your hard drive, choosing properties and selecting the location tab.

This was answered to the [question](https://superuser.com/q/948805/87805):

> Is there any way to change the recording folder for xbox app in windows 10?

I believe the passing audits should be clear enough and it shouldn't be picked up as an audit only because somebody marked it incorrectly (as a new question).

I think some [reviewer](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough) marked it mistakenly as a new question (which it wasn't) and other followed the same way:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. –

But it's definitely not a new question. It's an answer to the question, but short and such are allowed sometimes if they're straight to the topic.

[image]

---

Here is another [example](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/447102):

[image]

Comment: The audit system is automated.  There's a built-in assumption that the system will get some % of them wrong, which is why missing one occasionally is ignored.  The system isn't smart enough to recognize failure patterns (if most people fail a particular post, is it a bad test or a good one?).  Audit posts get re-used, so culling bad ones would save others indigestion.  But introducing any form of review, oversight, or "voting", would create workload, resource requirements, and unintended consequences.  The goal is to keep reviewers awake, and anger at failing unfairly works, too.

Comment: Your second example is a bad example — it truly is a poor answer.  (1) It’s imprecise — the “device(s) aren’t working … because either they aren’t properly configured, or they aren’t supported”.  Well, which is it?  (2) The answer provides no guidance on determining whether a device is supported, or configuring one that is — it’s basically a link with window dressing, and it doesn’t even provide an actual URL.  … … … …  At < 300 characters, this should have been a comment.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Less critical, but this may be the straw that breaks the camel’s back: it uses unprofessional language (“aint” [without an apostrophe!] and “dude”).  … … … …  There are raging debates re. whether this should be a factor in review/moderation decisions, but (4) it may be wrong.  The accepted answer to the question indicates that the asked-about driver(s) are, in fact, absent from NetBSD 6, “which was the development version of NetBSD until today more or less, where it [NetBSD 7] was released, though it hasn’t been announced yet.”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  A better meta-question might be: why was that answer in the Late Answers review queue to begin with, when it was posted *less than six hours after the question was asked?*  (It was, in fact, the ***first** answer* to the question.)